# Выравнять столбцы двух QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt

Есть задача: создать прямоугольное поле с чекбоксами. Для задачи идеально подходит `QGridLayout`.
Строки и столбцы этого поля должны иметь заголовки (у столбцов - совсем узкие).
Размеры поля - 10 в ширину и 20 в высоту. В высоту это поле на форму не лезет, поэтому я добавил `QScrollArea` и поместил `QGridLayout` туда.

Хочется зафиксировать заголовок: добавляю `QVBoxLayout`, помещаю туда ещё один `QGridLayout` и эту `QScrollArea`. В верхний grid помещаю виджеты с заголовками.

Пробегаюсь по всем item'ам, собираю макс.значение ширины из sizeHint().
И собственно проблема: за что надо "дёрнуть" grid'ы, чтобы выравнять ширину этих столбцов? В идеале ещё бы учесть ненулевую ширину рамки `QScrollArea`...

Микро-приложение для демонстрации всего вышеизложенного:
[image: скриншот]

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    resize(200, 150);
    auto * centralWidget = new QWidget (this);
    setCentralWidget (centralWidget);
    auto * mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout (centralWidget);

    // header
    auto * headerLayout = new QGridLayout ();
    mainLayout->addLayout (headerLayout);
    for (int column = 1; column < 5; column ++)
    {
        auto colName = QString ("%1").arg (column);
        auto * hdr = new QLabel (colName, this);
        headerLayout->addWidget (hdr, 0, column);
    }

    // items
    auto * scrollArea = new QScrollArea (this);
    mainLayout->addWidget (scrollArea);
    auto * scrollContents = new QWidget (scrollArea);
    scrollArea->setWidget (scrollContents);
    auto * itemsLayout = new QGridLayout (scrollContents);

    for (int row = 0; row < 15; row ++)
    {
        // row title
        auto rowName = QString ("Row %1").arg (row);
        auto * rowTitle = new QLabel (rowName, scrollContents);
        itemsLayout->addWidget (rowTitle, row, 0);
    
        // row contents
        for (int column = 1; column < 5; column ++)
        {
            auto * item = new QCheckBox (scrollContents);
            itemsLayout->addWidget (item, row, column);
        }
    }
    scrollContents->adjustSize();


    // adjust columns size
    for (int col = 0; col < headerLayout->columnCount(); ++col)
    {
        int width = 0;
    
        auto * item = headerLayout->itemAtPosition(0, col);
        if (item)
            width = item->sizeHint().width();

        for (auto row = 0; row < itemsLayout->rowCount(); ++row)
        {
            auto * item = itemsLayout->itemAtPosition(row, col);
        if (item)
            width = qMax (width,
                          item->sizeHint().width() );
        }

        qDebug() << "fit width:" << col << width;
        // FIXME this doesnt working!
        //headerLayout->setColumnMinimumWidth (col, width);
        //itemsLayout->setColumnMinimumWidth (col, width);
    }

}
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример: что есть, что нужно, что не получается. Кодом.

Comment: Кстати, не обязательно Компоновщикам/Виджетам указывать родителей, если они будут вложены или их вложат в виджеты/компоновщики

Например, после того как у виджета вызовите setLayout и передатите указатель на компоновщик, то у него родителем станет тот виджет

Comment: @Alexey , а почему Вы не хотите использовать вполне себе подходящий инструмент для такой задачи, как например `QTableView`?

Comment: @alexis031182, спасибо за совет. QTableView не использовал, т.к. до сих пор не разбирался в технологии MVC, а строил свои собственные велосипеды, а готовая QTableWidget вроде б не очень подходит.  Как-нибудь подумаю на эту тему...

Answer (score 1):

Кое-что получилось. Размер заголовка подстраивается под размер содержимого.

**.h**:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QResizeEvent>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QList <QWidget *> headerWidgets;
    QGridLayout * itemsLayout;

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    resize(200, 150);
    auto * centralWidget = new QWidget (this);
    setCentralWidget (centralWidget);
    auto * mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout (centralWidget);

    mainLayout->setSpacing(0);

    // header
    auto * header = new QWidget();
    header->setFixedHeight(20);

    auto * hdr = new QLabel ("", header);
    hdr->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);
    headerWidgets.append(hdr);

    for (int column = 1; column < 5; column ++)
    {
        auto colName = QString ("%1").arg (column);
        auto * hdr = new QLabel (colName, header);
        hdr->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);

        headerWidgets.append(hdr);
    }

    mainLayout->addWidget(header);

    // items
    auto * scrollArea = new QScrollArea (this);
    mainLayout->addWidget (scrollArea);
    auto * scrollContents = new QWidget (scrollArea);
    scrollArea->setWidget (scrollContents);
    itemsLayout = new QGridLayout (scrollContents);

    for (int row = 0; row < 15; row ++)
    {
        // row title
        auto rowName = QString ("Row %1").arg (row);
        auto * rowTitle = new QLabel (rowName, scrollContents);
        itemsLayout->addWidget (rowTitle, row, 0);

        // row contents
        for (int column = 1; column < 5; column ++)
        {
            auto * item = new QCheckBox (scrollContents);
            itemsLayout->addWidget (item, row, column);
        }
    }
    scrollContents->adjustSize();
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event) {
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);

    // adjust columns size
    for (int col = 0; col < headerWidgets.size(); ++col)
    {
        int width = 0;

        auto * item = headerWidgets[col];

        for (auto row = 0; row < itemsLayout->rowCount(); ++row)
        {
            auto * item = itemsLayout->itemAtPosition(row, col);
            if (item)
                width = qMax (width,
                              item->sizeHint().width() );
        }

        item->setFixedWidth(width);
        item->move(itemsLayout->itemAtPosition(0, col)->geometry().x(), item->y());
    }
}
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Потыкался-потыкался, получилось следующее:

- всем виджетам присвоил фиксированную ширину, равную макс. ширине столбца
- выставил для них QSizePolicy::Fixed

Для этого в цикле, считающем ширину столбцов, надо вызвать нечто следующее:

```
void MainWindow::SetFixWidth(QLayoutItem *item, int width)
{
    if (!item) return;
    auto * widget = item->widget();
    if (!widget) return;
    widget->setFixedWidth (width);
    auto szPol = widget->sizePolicy();
    szPol.setHorizontalPolicy (QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    widget->setSizePolicy (szPol);
}
```

...

```
SetFixWidth (headerLayout->itemAtPosition(0, col), width);
for (int row = 0; row < itemsLayout->rowCount(); ++row)
    SetFixWidth (itemsLayout->itemAtPosition(row, col), width);
```

И **после** этого поменять размер `scrollCointents`: `scrollContents->adjustSize();`

Да, чтобы всё корректно работало, надо в заголовке добавить пустые `QWidget` в нулевой столбец и в (n+1)-ый - один растянется до ширины содержимого, а второй заполнит "лишнее" место (ему не надо указывать fixed size).

Как посчитать ширину рамки этого scroll'а, пока не придумал. Документация сообщает, что всякие геометрические вещи (`pos()`, `mapTo...()`) доступны после отображения окна, а я всё это делаю до. Ну да ладно, тут костыль не жалко... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Всё же с `QTableWidget` можно добиться идентичного результата, не прибегая к построению сложных конструкций из большого кол-ва простых виджетов и менеджеров размещения (`QLayout`). С `QTableView` можно сделать всё тоже самое, просто в дополнение потребуется создать модель, в которой необходимо будет предварительно описать данные и их состояние (checked/unchecked). А с `QTableWidget` даже этого делать не нужно.

```
QTableWidget *tbl_wdg = new QTableWidget(this);
tbl_wdg->setRowCount(10);
tbl_wdg->setColumnCount(4);

for(int col = 0, cols = tbl_wdg->columnCount(); col < cols; ++col) {
    QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(col+1));
    tbl_wdg->setHorizontalHeaderItem(col, item);

    QHeaderView *header = tbl_wdg->horizontalHeader();
    header->setSectionResizeMode(col,QHeaderView::Fixed);
    header->resizeSection(col, 30);
}

for(int row = 0, rows = tbl_wdg->rowCount(); row < rows; ++row) {
    const QString str = QString("Row %1").arg(row);
    QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(str);
    tbl_wdg->setVerticalHeaderItem(row, item);

    QHeaderView *header = tbl_wdg->verticalHeader();
    header->setSectionResizeMode(row,QHeaderView::Fixed);
    header->resizeSection(row, 25);

    for(int col = 0, cols = tbl_wdg->columnCount(); col < cols; ++col) {
        QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
        item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled|Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
        tbl_wdg->setItem(row, col, item);
    }
}
```

Не обращайте внимания на указанные размеры секций. В данном случае я их подгонял под стиль виджетов своей ОС. На виндовс можно будет указать свои значения.

[image: Виджет-сетка]

Преимущество подхода очевидно: компактность кода и единственная точка входа для чтения и изменения состояния элементов - `QTableWidget`.